# How to autosave in TinyMCE For Flow?

Tags: tinymce, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, tinymce-plugins

We use TinyMCE For Flow 3.2.0 with Vaadin 14. An object from the class org.vaadin.tinymce.TinyMce is used. It seems like this object does not detect when the browser tab is closed. This can result in loss of written text when the user closes down the browser tab. It happens in this scenario:

The user writes text in the TinyMCE editor.
The user then closes down the browser tab.

Can this be solved with the "autosave plugin"? But this seems to be available only for regular TinyMCE and not for TinyMCE For Flow. Or is there some other way to solve this, so the text is saved to an org.vaadin.tinymce.TinyMce object when the browser tab is closed?